# Excel VBA to select "Yes to All" on prompt

Tags: excel, vba

In my code I copy a worksheet from one file to another I get a prompt saying that the name ranges already exists.  Click Yes / Yes to All / No ..."  I want it to automatically select yes to all.  Other posts show to use  Application.DisplayAlerts = False then turn it on at the end.  However when I add  Application.DisplayAlerts = False  the prompt selects No automatically so my sheet creates an external reference to the other file instead of the current version of the name.

Comment: Subjective statement:  I prefer to do this with a userform so I have more control.